# I can't access ng-model from a controller [AngularJS]

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm developing an e-commerce site for learnign purposes.

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="container">
    <form class="log-in-form" ng-controller="ControllerLogin">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="loginEmail">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="loginEmail" placeholder="Email" ng-model="email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="loginPass">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="loginPass" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password">
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="authenticate()">Login</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**Angular javascript**

```
    app.controller('ControllerLogin', ['$scope', '$http', 'ServiceLogin', function ($scope, $http, ServiceLogin) {
        $scope.authenticate = function () {
            console.log($scope.email);
            ServiceLogin.auth($scope.email, $scope.password)
                        .success(function (data) {
                            alert(data);
                        });
        }
}]);
```

Every time I console.log the $scope.email, or password. It throws an error of undefined. I'm just starting on angular and I don't know why is not getting the models, I thinks my code is correct. Any help you can give I will be gratefull.

Comment: hmm..seems it doesn't set itself until it is a valid email. If you change the input to `text` it works or if you input an actual email. I tried putting a `novalidate` on the form, but that did nothing.

Comment: As far as I know, `$scope.email` and and `$scope.password` are undefined until the form fields sets those values. What seems to be happening is that when the page's controller loads, both `$scope.email` and `$scope.password` are not initialized and hence are undefined. You can initialize them to empty strings. (`$scope.email =''"; ` `$scope.password =""`)

Comment: Ohh thanks! It was the invalid email thing. I think I should validate it by a RegEx since the button doesn't have the `type=submit` attr. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

From Angular site:

Note that novalidate is used to disable browser's native form validation.

The value of ngModel won't be set unless it passes validation for the input field. For example: inputs of type email must have a value in the form of user@domain.

Reference: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

So the reason it may be blank is that it's not a valid email.

You can look at their demo for the email type and see it in action.

I recommend adding:

```
{{email}}
<br>
{{password}}
```

somewhere in your html within the controller's HTML scope for your own debugging.

Good luck.